# Conditional check column value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have  document like below

```
 [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
        "status" : 1,
        "user_id" : 2,
    
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
        "status" : 2,
        "user_id" : 2,
    
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
        "status" : 2,
        "user_id" : 3,
    
    },
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
        "status" : 3,
        "user_id" : 4,
    
    }
    ]
```

status column can have value 1, 2 or 3. I want to match user_id only if status column value is 2 and document having status other than 2 will come in result as it is.

I have tried with match query

```
 db.collection.find({"status" : 1});
```

But it will only match the status

Now if my user id is 2 then output should b

```
[
     {
            "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
            "status" : 1,
            "user_id" : 2,
        
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
            "status" : 2,
            "user_id" : 2,
        
        },
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("601992e354787877866"),
            "status" : 3,
            "user_id" : 4,
        
        }
        ]
```

Here you can see document which status is 2 and user_id is not equal to 2 is not in expected output but for document which status is other than 2 will come is result

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e2Yi0-5mndF) what you want?. Also post an input example and expected output to understand better.

Comment: Updated the question with more details. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$or` operator: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y9vR2PEGYdI

```js
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      status: 2,
      user_id: 2
    },
    {
      status: {
        $ne: 2
      }
    }
  ]
})
```